# How to use an attribute of a Dexterity type as the url part

Tags: plone, dexterity

I'm writing a content type like the this with Dexterity:

```
class IArticle(form.Schema):

    title = schema.TextLine(
        title=_(u"Name"),
    )

    code = schema.TextLine(
        title=_(u"Code"),
    )
```

If some user creates a new article setting "foo" as title and "bar" as code, the title will be "foo" and the article URL will be ".../foo". How can I get that the content URL be ".../bar"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want to do is influence the [name chooser](http://plone.org/products/dexterity/documentation/manual/developer-manual/reference/manipulating-content-objects), and you can do that with a [custom behavior](http://plone.org/products/dexterity/documentation/manual/behaviors/creating-and-registering-behaviors) for your interface.

Subclassing the `INameForTitle` interface is the easiest:

```
from plone.app.content.interfaces import INameFromTitle
from zope import interface, component

from ..types.interfaces import IArticle


class INameFromCode(INameFromTitle):
    pass

class ArticleCodeAsTitle(object):
    component.adapts(IArticle)
    interface.implements(INameFromCode)

    def __init__(self, context):
        self.context = context

    @property
    def title(self):
        return self.context.code
```

The default name chooser tries to adapt the new-to-be-added object to the `INameForTitle` interface, then if that succeeds, will use the `.title` attribute to build a new name for the object. By implementing a subclass of that interface as an adapter for your `IArticle` objects, you get to substitute the title for your `.code` field instead, thus making sure that that is used for new names instead.

Register this as:

```
<configure
    xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope"
    xmlns:plone="http://namespaces.plone.org/plone"
    i18n_domain="your.i18n.domain"
    >

<plone:behavior
    title="ArticleCode"
    description="Use .code as the title when choosing a new object name"
    provides=".articlecode.INameFromCode"
    factory=".articlecode.ArticleCodeAsTitle"
    for="..types.interfaces.IArticle"
    />

</configure>
```

and add this behavior to your `Article` type definition *instead* of the `INameFromTitle` behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Create a **custom behavior** to set the **object id** to the `code` **attribute value**:

- http://plone.org/products/dexterity/documentation/manual/behaviors/creating-and-registering-behaviors